# Next.js fetch get an ECONNREFUSED error in Docker (Strapi as backend)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, strapi

Good day everyone. I set up a simple next.js page to get data from Strapi via API. It runs fine locally. But when I run them in Docker, I got a ECONNREFUSED error.

here is the error:

```
error - TypeError: fetch failed
frontend  |     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
frontend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
frontend  |     at async getStaticProps (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:38:17)
frontend  |     at async Object.renderToHTML (/usr/local/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:384:20)
frontend  |     at async doRender (/usr/local/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:708:34)
frontend  |     at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.isManualRevalidate.isManualRevalidate (/usr/local/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:813:28)
frontend  |     at async /usr/local/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:80:36 {
frontend  |   cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
frontend  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
frontend  |     errno: -111,
frontend  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
frontend  |     syscall: 'connect',
frontend  |     address: '127.0.0.1',
frontend  |     port: 1337
frontend  |   },
frontend  |   page: '/'
frontend  | }
```

And here is the code in Next.js:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/posts')
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    props: { data },
  }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
    image: backend:latest
    # restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./backend/.env
    volumes:
      - strapi_data:/usr/local/backend/strapi/.tmp
      - strapi_upload:/usr/local/backend/strapi/public/uploads
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
    image: frontend:latest
    # restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./frontend/.env
    volumes:
      - node_modules_next:/usr/local/frontend/node_modules
      - next_folder:/usr/local/frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - 'backend'
volumes:
  node_modules_next:
  next_folder:
  strapi_data:
  strapi_upload:
```

I followed this [guide](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/middlewares.html#internal-middlewares-configuration-reference) to set up the middleware in Strapi:

```
export default [
  "strapi::errors",
  "strapi::security",
  // 'strapi::cors',
  {
    name: "strapi::cors",
    config: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
      headers: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Origin", "Accept"],
      keepHeaderOnError: true,
    },
  },
  "strapi::poweredBy",

  "strapi::logger",
  "strapi::query",
  "strapi::body",
  "strapi::session",
  "strapi::favicon",
  "strapi::public",
];
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried to change getStaticProps to getServerSideProps, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself. Once I run docker-compose on my server, I change the fetch link from http://localhost:1337/api/posts to http://{ip}:1337/api/posts

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a link on your frontend like that:

```
frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
    image: frontend:latest
    # restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./frontend/.env
    volumes:
      - node_modules_next:/usr/local/frontend/node_modules
      - next_folder:/usr/local/frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - 'backend'
    links:
      - backend
```

And then connect to http://backend:1337/api/posts

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is not new I want to share my solution for this issue.

The frontend container needs to access the backend container during build to create the static sites. However, when building the frontend container, it can’t resolve the backend container name to an IP and also does not have access to the localhost, since localhost only refers to its own container and not to the machine (the „docker host“). Also a docker bridge network is not available during build.

To make the backend container available during build, you need to tell docker, to use the docker host network like:

```
build:
  context: frontend
  dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
  network: host
```

When performing API calls to your backend, you now should be able to use `http://localhost:1337` from your frontend to access Strapi and you bud should succeed. This is only for build. When switching to client side rendering, you should use a bridge network or stick to host networking. In my scenario I used a bridge network and since I am using graphQL with Strapi, I created two Apollo clients, one for the build/the server side which uses localhost and one for the client side which uses my nginx backend domain.

Answer (score 1):

## Here is what actually happens

at the time you build your docker compose project. it's best practice to use your project service-name as host.

here is the example of networking in docker compose:

```
# this is your docker compose backend

backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: .docker/dev.dockerfile
    image: backend:latest
    # restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./backend/.env
    volumes:
      - strapi_data:/usr/local/backend/strapi/.tmp
      - strapi_upload:/usr/local/backend/strapi/public/uploads
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
```

here is how you fetch from frontend:

```
const res = await fetch('http://backend:1337/api/posts')
```

## but in your case it still will fail

here the explanation:

1. you build a docker compose project of **next js with getStaticProp**
2. its fetching the static params at **built-time**
3. when the docker compose build the image **the network not yet established**

** if this help someone i will continue my explanation **